# Redux: how to send time consuming actions

Tags: redux, react-redux, state, action, updates

How to reflect state changes between time consuming actions in Redux/React? I
have a simple chess game against AI. When I make a move I want to update the state and run the AI computation which takes few seconds. Before that moment I want my move to be reflected in the state. Here is the example:

```
  takeTurnOnPieceMoved = (code, fc, fr, tc, tr) => {
    //* My turn *//
    const board = new Board(this.props.board)

    // Make the turn and update the board state
    board.makeMove(code, fc, fr, tc, tr)
    
    // This line dispatches the action to set the new state of the board to the App's state (which is more general state)
    // I expect the UI to be updated (somehow) after this call
    this.props.setBoardState(board.state)

    //* AI turn *//
    const stateWithMyMove = board.state

    // Create new board
    const newBoard = new Board(stateWithMyMove)

    // Find the best move to take
    const aiMove = newBoard.getBestMove()

    // Apply that best move to reflect it in the board state
    newBoard.makeMove(aiMove.code, aiMove.fc, aiMove.fr, aiMove.tc, aiMove.tr)

    // Set the new state of the board with the ai move in it
    this.props.setBoardState(newBoard.state)
  }
```

Comment: What is time consuming? If it's client code then you can use [a thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) with [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) if it's a request to a server then you can use thunk.

Comment: I meant that AI job to find the best move takes several seconds which freezes UI until the calculations are done. I think the Web Workers is exactly what I need. Will dig into this. Thanks.